# How can i `ecrecover` in solidity to verify the digest produced by `web3.utils.soliditySha3` in JS side?

Tags: solidity, web3js, signature, keccak

Javascript side:

```js
id = 128
uri = "xxx://xxx"
hash = web3.utils.soliditySha3(id,uri)
sign = web3.eth.accounts.sign(hash1, privateKey)
```

Solidity side:

```
function(uint256 id, string memory uri,bytes v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s){
  digest = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(id, uri));
  signer = ecrecover(digest, v, r, s);
}
```

`signer` always mismatch with the `prviateKey` i use to sign the message. What's the correct way to work with signature using `soliditySha3`?

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need to use solidity for that you can use directly `web3` like: `web3.eth.accounts.recover(hash, v, r, s);` (to get the `signer` address).

See https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth-accounts.html?highlight=recover#recover

But if you still want to use solidity you need to deploy the contract with the `ecrecover` function and call it with `web3`.

To extract `v, r, s` form the signed message you can do this:

```
const Transaction = require('ethereumjs-tx')
const tx = web3.eth.getTransaction(txHash) // to get tx.v tx.r tx.s
```